# Python Large list sorting and storage

Tags: python, list, sorting, heap

I'm currently working with some very large lists (50 to 100 million entries) of information where each item in the list is in the form of [float,(string_1,string_2)]

I'm adding elements to the list in an unsorted manner, and would eventually like to have a list that is sorted by the float value. For example I would have a list that looks like this:

```
[ [0.5,(A,B)], [-0.15,(B,C)], [0.3,(A,C)], [-0.8,(A,D)] ]
```

and then sort it  to get

```
[ [0.5,(A,B)], [0.3,(A,C)], [-0.15,(B,C)], [-0.8,(A,D)] ]
```

Currently I'm using heapq to add items as I go along and then using sorted(heap) to ultimately give me the list I need. My question is: is there a better way to go about adding millions of items to a list and sorting them that won't crash my computer? Holding a list that long and then sorting it is causing some issues with my RAM.

Comment: With that many entries, you should **really** consider writing your data to a file as it is collected.

Comment: Why not using `generators` ? Instead of storing your data into a list then sorting it, create a generator then sort it once.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: A generator will still be converted to a `list` in memory to sort it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger True, but you'll escape storing the whole list in memory then sorting it again.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: You won't. If you just make the `list` up front (without pointless use of `heapq`), then call `.sort()` it's exactly the same. It saves if you're calling `sorted(mygenerator)` vs. `sorted(mylist)`, but if you already have `mylist`, calling `mylist.sort()` avoids the memory overhead too.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes i see. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 7):

`sorted()` creates an entirely distinct list, so doubles the RAM needed for the massive list.  Use a list's `.sort()` method instead - that sorts the list in-place.

And unless there's something you haven't told us, leave `heapq` out of it entirely.  Putting the entries in a heap serves no purpose I can think of.  Just use a list's `.append()` method to add new entries, and apply `.sort(reverse=True)` to the list at end.

If you're still running out of RAM, then you simply can't solve this problem entirely in memory, and will need to craft an approach merging disk files.

## LIVING WITH "TOO SMALL" RAM

In the worst case, even the list all by itself can't fit in available memory.  You can still create the sorted sequence, but it requires writing sorted chunks to disk and merging them later.  For the merging part, `heapq` *is* useful.  Here's an example:

```
import pickle
import heapq

MAXPERFILE = 100  # the array will never get bigger than this

def getfname(i):
    return "pickled%d.dat" % i

filenum = 0
def dumptofile(a):  # dump the array to file, as pickled data
    global filenum
    fname = getfname(filenum)
    with open(fname, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(len(a), f)
        for x in a:
            pickle.dump(x, f)
    filenum += 1

# generate some random data
import random
a = []
for _ in range(1012):  # 10 "full" files with some leftovers
    a.append(random.random())
    if len(a) == MAXPERFILE:
        a.sort(reverse=True)
        dumptofile(a)
        del a[:]
if a:
    a.sort(reverse=True)
    dumptofile(a)

print("number of files written:", filenum)

# now merge the files together; first a function
# to generate the file contents, one at a time
def feedfile(i):
    fname = getfname(i)
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        count = pickle.load(f)
        for _ in range(count):
            yield pickle.load(f)

for x in heapq.merge(*(feedfile(i) for i in range(filenum)),
                     reverse=True):
    print(x)
```

Max memory use can be made smaller by decreasing `MAXPERFILE`, although performance will be better the larger `MAXPERFILE`.  Indeed, if `MAXPERFILE` is small enough and the total amount of data is large enough, the merging code may die with an OS "too many open files" error.